# FB Wall Poster - Message Post(Post and notification sended.)/ Link Post ( it posted but notification not sended)

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

here is the code, this code works very well when the post didnt include a link on the "link field", a message can be send with or without a link inside "field message" a link posted in the field message it will look like a clickable text link
(http://www.mylinkposted.com/withoutmetadata/) you can send a post like:

> Hi, i finally finish my new website
>
> http://mywebsite.com
>
> i'll waiting for some feed back, from your experience.

But if a link is writed(copied) inside "link field" it will be extracted meta data from it and the post will include description,caption,title,image, source...
and the post it will look like if the user have shared a link on other user feed/wall with all the post parameters on it, and looks prety well, but notification its not coming to notification stream, and looks really spammy just post and not send a notification, what do you think can solve this issue?

```
                $app_id        = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

                $app_secret    = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

                $site_url      = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/app00/index.php";



                try{
                    include_once "src/facebook.php";
                }catch(Exception $e){
                    error_log($e);
                }

                $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                    'appId'     => $app_id,
                    'secret'    => $app_secret,
                    ));


                $user = $facebook->getUser();

                if($user){

                    try{        
                        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
                    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
                        error_log($e);
                        $user = NULL;
                    }

                }

                if($user){
                    // Get logout URL
                    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
                }else{
                    // Get login URL
                    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                        'scope'         => 'publish_stream user_groups',
                        'redirect_uri'  => $site_url,
                        ));
                }

                if($user){

                    $queries = array(
                        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user),
                        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/friends'),
                        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/groups'),
                        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/likes'),
                        );


                    try{
                        $batchResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');
                    }catch(Exception $o){
                        error_log($o);
                    }


                    //string. Decode for use as a PHP array.
                    $user_info      = json_decode($batchResponse[0]['body'], TRUE);
                    $friends_list   = json_decode($batchResponse[1]['body'], TRUE);
                    $groups         = json_decode($batchResponse[2]['body'], TRUE);
                    $pages          = json_decode($batchResponse[3]['body'], TRUE);



                    if(isset($_POST['submit_x'])){
                        if($_POST['message'] || $_POST['link'] || $_POST['picture']) {
                            $body = array(
                                'message'       => $_POST['message'],
                                'link'          => $_POST['link'],
                                );

                            $batchPost=array();

                            $i=1;
                            $flag=1;
                            foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
                                if(strpos($key,"id_") === 0) {
                                    $batchPost[] = array('method' => 'POST', 'relative_url' => "/$value/feed", 'body' => http_build_query($body));
                                    if($i++ == 50) {
                                        try{
                                            $multiPostResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.urlencode(json_encode($batchPost)), 'POST');                          
                                        }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
                                            error_log($e);
                                            echo("Batch Post Failed");
                                        }
                                        $flag=0;
                                        unset($batchPost);
                                        $i=1;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if(isset($batchPost)) {
                                try{
                                    $multiPostResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.urlencode(json_encode($batchPost)), 'POST');
                                }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
                                    error_log($e);
                                    echo("Batch Post Failed");
                                }
                                $flag=0;
                            }

                        }
                        else {
                            $flag=2;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Don't write spambots.  Facebook will block your app and take away your development access.

Comment: it can look like that but there is not, it has a menu and it only can be posted by the user itself, selecting who friend will receive the post and have limitation to how many friends will be visible to select.